# Docker compose wants engine > 1.10.0 but it already has engine 1.12.3

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am getting this error:

```
556 zbeckman:source$ docker-compose up
ERROR: The Docker Engine version is less than the minimum required by Compose. Your current project requires a Docker Engine of version 1.10.0 or greater.
```

Which makes absolutely no sense, since I'm using the latest version of Docker (I'm running Docker on Mac and recently installed the latest version):

```
558 zbeckman:source$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.8.1, build 878cff1
561 zbeckman:source$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 23:26:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.24, server API version: 1.21)
562 zbeckman:source$
```

And... after playing with my configuration for a while (which seemed to be working as far as docker images were concerned), now docker itself is giving this:

```
527 zbeckman:source$ docker ps
Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.24, server API version: 1.21)
```

I've tried completely removing Docker from my system, downloading the absolutely latest image, reinstalling... and even rebooting, just in case.

*Edit*
New update. After more fiddling around (I found an old instance of VirtualBox, which I removed, and I also deleted my ~/.docker directory to get a clean start)... Now Docker.app hangs when I try to start it. The process is running:

```
502 zbeckman:~$ ps ax|grep -i docker
  582   ??  S      0:00.17 /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker
  725 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep -i docker
```

But I see no Docker icon in my task bar. Any attempt to use docker fails:

```
503 zbeckman:~$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Comment: Since you cleared out VirtualBox, have you tried uninstalling Docker and reinstalling?

Comment: This might also be useful: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/

Comment: I've completely removed VirtualBox *and* Docker, and reinstalled. I even tried reinstalling Mac OS. And I can't troubleshoot, since I never get the whale icon in my toolbar – it completely hangs when I start it up.

Answer (score 2):

```
Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.24, server API version: 1.21)
```

That line indicates that you're talking to a server that hasn't been upgraded. If you are using docker-machine, run a `docker-machine ls` to see what you are talking to (possibly a VM, possibly a completely different location). You can also check the value of `$DOCKER_HOST` in your shell to see what server you are talking to.

If you don't want to upgrade your server, then run `export DOCKER_CLIENT_API=1.21` to force the client to use an older version of the API when talking to the server.

Comment: Added a few more bits of information above. `docker-machine ls` just returns empty (headings, nothing running). I've done everything I can think of to clean out old installs, downloaded the latest Docker, and... I'm out of ideas. I *do* want to upgrade, that's what I've been trying to do all day; ever since installing that latest build, I've been unable to use Docker...

Comment: From your update it sounds like we went from bad to worse and my above advice will no longer help with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution**

After reading up on [#8](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8) and [#107](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/107), I tried a lot of hacking. Finally... after many attempts, doing this:

```
sudo launchctl remove com.docker.vmnetd
```

And running Docker.app seems to have solved the problem. Docker is now functioning correctly as far as I can tell.

Seems there should be some kind of check in the app so a dead process and a beachball is not the only result.